# What is a restful way to implement this proposed API?

Tags: rest

So I'm trying to develop a music player for my office with a restful API.  In a nutshell, the API will be able to download music from youtube and load it into the current playlist of a running MPD instance.  I also want to be able to control playback / volume with the API

Here's kind of what I was thinking so far:

```
Endpoint: /queue
    Methods:
        GET: Gets the current MPD playlist
        POST: Accepts JSON with these arguments:
           source-type: specify the type of the source of the music (usually youtube, but i might want to expand later to support pulling from soundcloud, etc)
           source-desc: Used in conjunction with source-type, ie, if source-type were youtube, this would be a youtube search query
           It would use these arguments to go out and find the song you want and put it in the queue
        DELETE: Would clear the queue

Endpoint: /playbackcontrol
    Methods:
        GET: Returns volume, whether playing, paused, or stopped, etc
        POST: Accepts JSON with these arguments:
            operation: describe the operation you want (ie, next, previous, volume adjust)
            optional_value: value for operations that need a value (like volume)
```

So that's basically what I'm thinking right now.  I know this is really high level, I just wanted to get some input to see if I'm on the right track.  Does this look like an acceptable way to implement such an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DELETE to clear the queue is not cool. PUT an empty queue representation instead. This will also come in handy later when you want to be able to rearrange items in the queue, remove them one by one etc.—you can GET the current queue, apply changes and PUT it back.

Volume is clearly better modeled as a separate `/status/volume` resource with GET and PUT. Maybe PATCH if you absolutely need distinct “volume up” and “volume down” operations (that is, if your client will not be keeping track of current volume).

Ditto for the playing/paused/stopped status: GET/PUT `/status/playback`.

To seed the client with the current status, make `GET /status` respond with a summary of what’s going on: current track, volume, playing/paused.

Comment: Great tips!  I'll definitely be using most if not all of these.  This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: What do you think of my method of adding music to the queue?  Also, how would you go about implementing a "shuffle" function into this API?

Comment: @DanCauley POST for adding to the queue is just right. Shuffle: there are two ways (as in normal desktop players): you can set a special “shuffle on” mode, or you can actually reposition the items in the queue. The former is the same as with volume or playback. The latter, I think it would be best to GET the current queue, shuffle it on the client, and PUT it back.

Comment: Thanks again for the input!  I'd upvote you but I don't have enough reputation yet :P

Comment: Hey Vasilly!  I've got another quick question:

What do you think would be the most restful way to implement the "Next" oepration?  That is, jumping to the next song in the playlist?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following 2 main modules:

```
playlist/{trackId}
    source
    index
player
    playing
    track
    time
    volume
```

Playlist:

- adding a track: `POST playlist {source: ...}`
- removing a track: `DELETE playlist/{id}`
- ordering tracks: `PUT playlist/{id}/index 123`
- get track list: `GET playlist`

Player:

- loading a track: `PUT player/track {id: 123}`
- rewind a track: `PUT player/time 0`
- stop the player: `PUT player/playing false`
- start the player: `PUT player/playing true`
- adjust volume: `PUT player/volume .95`
- get current status: `GET player`

Ofc you should use the proper RDF vocab for link relations and for describing your data. You can find it probably [here](http://schema.org/docs/search_results.html#q=play).